# How do I add the thousand separator for a pie chart value?

Tags: c#, telerik, pie-chart, separator, dataformat

I have a telerik pie chart where the values for labels would be like 6413.857 MWh, 75433.695 MWh. How do I add the thousand separator(6,413.857 MWh, 75,433.695 MWh) into these values that display on the chart?

I have tried to format using dataformat string but it will either not affect the value at all or give a blank.

```
 <div class="pie">
         <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="PChartConsumption" Visible="false" Width="100%" Height="300" Transitions="true" Skin="Silk">
            <ChartTitle Text="Consumption in MWh for all the price plans">
                <Appearance Align="Center" Position="Top">
                </Appearance>
            </ChartTitle>
            <Legend>
                <Appearance Position="Right" Visible="true">
                </Appearance>
            </Legend>
            <PlotArea>
                <Series>
                    <telerik:PieSeries DataFieldY="Consumption" ColorField="Color" ExplodeField="false"
                        NameField="PricePlanType">
                        <LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="{0:#,###.000} MWh">
                           <ClientTemplate>#= kendo.format(\'{0:N3}\', dataItem.Consumption)#</ClientTemplate>
                        </LabelsAppearance>
                        <TooltipsAppearance Color="Black" />
                    </telerik:PieSeries>
                </Series>
            </PlotArea>
        </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
    </div>
```

The datasource of the pie chart

```
 DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Consumption"));
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PricePlanType"));
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Color"));
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsExploded"));
        string fixedCon, sigCon, sigPlusCon, dodtCon, wspsCon;
        if (consumptionFixed > 0)
            fixedCon = consumptionFixed.ToString("#.000");
        else
            fixedCon = "0";

        if (consumptionSignature > 0)
            sigCon = consumptionSignature.ToString("#.000");
        else
            sigCon = "0";

        if (consumptionSignaturePlus > 0)
            sigPlusCon = consumptionSignaturePlus.ToString("#.000");
        else
            sigPlusCon = "0";

        if (consumptionDOT > 0)
            dodtCon = consumptionDOT.ToString("#.000");
        else
            dodtCon = "0";

        if (consumptionWSPSubscription > 0)
            wspsCon = consumptionWSPSubscription.ToString("#.000");
        else
            wspsCon = "0";

        tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { fixedCon, PricePlanConstants.GetName(PricePlanEnum.Fixed), "Red", false });
        tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { sigCon, PricePlanConstants.GetName(PricePlanEnum.Signature), "Blue", false });
        tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { sigPlusCon, PricePlanConstants.GetName(PricePlanEnum.SignaturePlus), "Green", false });
        tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { dodtCon, PricePlanConstants.GetName(PricePlanEnum.DOT), "Yellow", false });
        tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { wspsCon, PricePlanConstants.GetName(PricePlanEnum.WSPSubscription), "Pink", true });
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `ClientTemplate` in `PieSeries`: `ClientTemplate="#= kendo.format(\'{0:N3}\', dataItem.Consumption)#"`? Since presented number uses 3 decimal places, it should be adjusted to `{0:N3}`.

Comment: Just tried and got the error  Type 'Telerik.Web.UI.PieSeries' does not have a public property named 'ClientTemplate'. Not really sure how and where to add the client template.

Comment: How about using `ClientTemplate` like this one: `<telerik:PieSeries ...><ClientTemplate>#= kendo.format(\'{0:N3}\', dataItem.Consumption)#</ClientTemplate></telerik:PieSeries>`? Or probably you want to set series: `var item = PChartConsumption.PlotArea.Series[0] as PieSeries;` then in foreach loop use `item.TooltipsAppearance.ClientTemplate="#= kendo.format(\'{0:N3}\', dataItem.Consumption)#"`?

Comment: Still having the same error. I put the client template in the LabelsAppearance but still does not add the "," to the format of the label. Label appears as 6413.857 and 75433.695 still

Comment: Also currently using the dataTable as the datasource for the pie chart and rebinding data after clickof a button.